# Need to install libapache2-mod-php onto apache2.2.22

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, package

I have to launch old project using apache 2.2.22. (NOT 2.4.x)
So I downgraded from 2.4 to 2.2 and this seems to be OK.
But then I have to install libapache so I use:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

and this results

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php: Depends: apache2-api-20120211
Depends: apache2 (>=2.4)
```

Does somebody know how to install libapache2-mod-php to the old apache 2.2.22?

Comment: You will also have to find an old libapache2-mod-php5 that matches with Apache 2.2.22

Comment: Tanks, but thats obvious. Do you have repositories or manuals?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use 2.4? There aren't that many breaking changes between the two versions.

Comment: No but I do have a thing called Google Search, but I dont have any idea what version of UBUNTU you are using so I cannot be more precise

Comment: Im using 14.04 with apache 2.2.22. If you find out how to solve my problem post that as answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Had to set priority of repositories for php* and libapache2-mod-php. Solved.